# how to save an object in object in real-time database, Firebase (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, object

I would like to save data into the real-time database of Firebase, but I run into a problem. I've only been working with Kotlin for 1 month, and unfortunately I don't know how to save data to the real-time database in this form, as shown in the picture.

My current code is this:

```
data class userData(
    val username: String,
    val uid: String,
)

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Userdata")
val user = uid?.let {
    userData("Test1", it)
}

if (uid != null) {
    database.child(uid).setValue(user).addOnSuccessListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

My database. The same way, I would like to be able to save it with Kotlin
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbAsC.png

The problem is, I don't know how to save the data object to the database, is there an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to improve your `data class` for `userData` model like below because there are some cases, you will have error about it in future.

```
data class userData(
    val username: String? = null,
    val uid: String? = null,
)
```

To answer your question, you need to create a new `data class` for the `data` model like below.

```
data class UserDataExtra(
    val banned: Boolean? = null
)
```

Next you just need to implement inside the `addOnSuccessListener` like below.

```
if (uid != null) {
    database.child(uid).setValue(user).addOnSuccessListener {
        //Here you will update new model for userDataExtra
        val userExtra = UserDataExtra (false)
        database.child(uid).child("UserDataExtra").setValue(userExtra )..addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success saved with data extra!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Get instance of your database:**

val database = Firebase.database.reference

**The call to write to your database:**

```
database.child("UserData").child(uid).setValue(user)
```

**To Read from your database once:**

```
database.child("UserData").child(uid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.i("firebase", "Got value ${it.value}")
}.addOnFailureListener{
    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
}
```

This article has the solution to what you're looking for.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=en&authuser=0#read_data

It is also possible to listen for changes in your database and update accordingly mentioned in the article above.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you forgot is to tell the table name inside the database.
You should try using `database.child(tableName).child(uid).setValue(user)`
and then the addOnSuccessListener